# Wordpress publish_post hook not getting featured image and meta on first publish, but works on updating title

Tags: plugin-development, save-post, publish, autosave

I've been struggling to find a solution for this and I don't know if it's the Gutenberg editor or if it's the hook `publish_post`.

Hook:

```php
function api_method($post_id) {
    // If this is just a revision, don't send request
    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get Post Object
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    open_log($post);

    $postData = array(
        'unit' => get_post_meta($post_id, 'open_unit', true),
        'abstract' => get_post_meta($post_id, 'open_abstract', true),
        'image'   => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post, 'full'),
        'title' => get_the_title($post),
        'url' => get_the_permalink($post),
    );

    open_log($postData);

    $auth = base64_encode(get_option('open_up_username') . ':' . get_option('open_up_api_key'));

    $status = get_post_meta($post_id, 'open_active', true) ? 'active':'paused';
    $openUnit = get_post_meta($post_id, 'open_unit', true);
//  $postMeta = get_post_meta($post_id);

//  open_log($postMeta);

    $responseApi = wp_remote_post(OPEN_REMOTE_POST, array(
            'headers' => array('Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $auth),
            'body' => 'unit='.$openUnit.'&status='.$status.'&abstract='.get_post_meta($post_id, 'open_abstract', true).'&image='.get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full').'&title='.get_the_title($post).'&url='.get_the_permalink($post)
        )
    );

    $response = new WP_REST_Response($responseApi, 200);

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($responseApi);

    $responseBody = ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) ? json_decode( $body, true ) : null;

    $unit = isset($responseBody['unit']) ? $responseBody['unit'] : '';

    open_log($responseBody);
    open_log($unit);

    $update = update_post_meta($post_id, 'open_unit', $unit);

    open_log($update);
}
```

I'm using the post meta, featured image and title to post to a third party API. The API verifies the data and then returns a unit hash which I store in the post meta `open_unit`.

I'm also logging the data and responses in a log.txt file, and I'm getting this on initial publish:

```
object(WP_Post)#4421 (24) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(240)
  ["post_author"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["post_date"]=>
  string(19) "2021-05-07 09:57:28"
  ["post_date_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2021-05-07 07:57:28"
  ["post_content"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(11) "New post v3"
  ["post_excerpt"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["comment_status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["ping_status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["post_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_name"]=>
  string(11) "new-post-v3"
  ["to_ping"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pinged"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2021-05-07 09:57:28"
  ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2021-05-07 07:57:28"
  ["post_content_filtered"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["guid"]=>
  string(31) "https://grace.open-up.it/?p=240"
  ["menu_order"]=>
  int(0)
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(4) "post"
  ["post_mime_type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comment_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
}

array(5) {
  ["unit"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["abstract"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["image"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["title"]=>
  string(11) "New post v3"
  ["url"]=>
  string(45) "https://grace.open-up.it/recipes/new-post-v3/"
}

array(2) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["message"]=>
  string(83) "Open Up - Si è verificato un problema con l'elaborazione dell'immagine in evidenza"
}

string(0) ""

int(1256)
```

The API is returning and saying that the image is invalid which is true because the image url is not showing in the `$postData` array.

After I edit the title and save, it logs below:

```
object(WP_Post)#4420 (24) {
  ["ID"]=>
  int(240)
  ["post_author"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["post_date"]=>
  string(19) "2021-05-07 09:57:28"
  ["post_date_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2021-05-07 07:57:28"
  ["post_content"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_title"]=>
  string(12) "Edit post v3"
  ["post_excerpt"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_status"]=>
  string(7) "publish"
  ["comment_status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["ping_status"]=>
  string(4) "open"
  ["post_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_name"]=>
  string(11) "new-post-v3"
  ["to_ping"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["pinged"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_modified"]=>
  string(19) "2021-05-07 09:57:40"
  ["post_modified_gmt"]=>
  string(19) "2021-05-07 07:57:40"
  ["post_content_filtered"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["post_parent"]=>
  int(0)
  ["guid"]=>
  string(31) "https://grace.open-up.it/?p=240"
  ["menu_order"]=>
  int(0)
  ["post_type"]=>
  string(4) "post"
  ["post_mime_type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comment_count"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["filter"]=>
  string(3) "raw"
}

array(5) {
  ["unit"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["abstract"]=>
  string(213) "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
  ["image"]=>
  string(79) "https://grace.open-up.it/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/7540312530_37e709d2f4_b.jpg"
  ["title"]=>
  string(12) "Edit post v3"
  ["url"]=>
  string(45) "https://grace.open-up.it/recipes/new-post-v3/"
}

array(2) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["unit"]=>
  string(36) "e12213d3-058b-40f9-b487-a1776470f37b"
}

string(36) "e12213d3-058b-40f9-b487-a1776470f37b"

bool(true)
```

I really am confused about how the Wordpress editor handles the state for publishing and confused why it's not returning the meta and featured image. I found this user having the same issue(I think) with the same hook and isn't resolved either https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666305/get-featured-image-url-after-publishing

I have also done a recording of this https://share.getcloudapp.com/eDujbqJp

I hope someone can advise or give direction regarding this. Thank you in advance

Comment: I think wordpress do CRUD operations with post first and if it was succesfull (post_id returned) he works with post meta (etc.) using this post_id. I guess this publish_post hook is not for your purpose, because at the moment it fires first time, post_meta and post attachment is not set yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info @anton. Is there another hook I can use in place or in conjunction to get it work on getting the meta and attachment?

Comment: I dont think hooks like 'save_post' will work to, because when I create custom post meta I use this hook to get post id and save post meta by myself. Maybe `updated_post_meta` hook? Fires immediately after updating metadata of a specific type. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/updated_meta_type_meta/

Comment: Thank you so much @anton, the `updated_post_meta` hook works perfectly!

Comment: If you agree, I will add it as an answer to remove this question from unanswered list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know if it's the Gutenberg editor or if it's the hook
> `publish_post`

The hook itself works, and if you used the old WordPress post editor, then the issue in question would **not** happen.

So you can say that it's the Gutenberg/block editor.

> why it's not returning the meta and featured image

Because Gutenberg uses the REST API, and by the time the `publish_post` hook is fired (when `wp_update_post()` is called — see [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.1/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L808)), the post's featured image and other meta data have not yet been saved/processed.

### How to fix the issue

*If you're using WordPress **5.6** or later*, then for what you're trying to do, you would want to use the [`wp_after_insert_post` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_after_insert_post/) which works well with the old/classic editor and the Gutenberg/block editor.

Excerpt from https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/20/new-action-wp_after_insert_post-in-wordpress-5-6/:

> ## New action wp_after_insert_post in WordPress 5.6.
>
> The new action  `wp_after_insert_post`  has been added to WordPress
> 5.6 to allow theme and  plugin  developers to run custom code after a post and its terms and  meta  data have been updated.
>
> The  `save_post`  and related actions have commonly been used for this
> purpose but these  hooks  can fire  *before*  terms and meta data are
> updated outside of the classic editor. (For example in the  REST API,
> via the  block  editor, within the  Customizer  and when an auto-draft
> is created.)
>
> The new action sends up to four parameters:
>
> - `$post_id`  The post ID has been updated, an  `integer`.
> - `$post`  The full post object in its updated form, a  `WP_Post`  object.
> - `$updated`  Whether the post has been updated or not, a  `boolean`.
> - `$post_before`  The full post object prior to the update, a  `WP_Post`  object. For new posts this is  `null`.

And here's an example which mimics the `publish_post` hook, i.e. the `// your code here` part below would only run if the post is being published and is *not* already published (the post status is not already `publish`):

```php
add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'my_wp_after_insert_post', 10, 4 );
// Note: As of writing, the third parameter is actually named $update and not $updated.
function my_wp_after_insert_post( $post_id, $post, $update, $post_before ) {
    if ( 'publish' !== $post->post_status                           ||
        ( $post_before && 'publish' === $post_before->post_status ) ||
        wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )
    ) {
        return;
    }

    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and direction in handling this with both classic and Gutenberg editors. Have tried and testing this and works better than the other answer as it handles all fields that’s inserted/updated.

Comment: Yes that's right, the "all fields" is the key point - the hook runs only after all metadata are saved, hence that hook is more suitable in your case. 

Comment: Thank you, this snippet saved the day for me! Various other WP hooks i've tried such as transition_post_status and post_save see $post before the meta has been saved so don't return what I expected when doing has_post_thumbnail() for example. It seems wp_after_insert_post is the only way to truly access the day when the save is fully complete.

Answer (score 0):

`{$new_status}_{$post->post_type}` hook or `publish_post` fires when a post is transitioned from one status to another. At a moment this hook fires, no post meta is saved yet (on post creation).

If you need to use custom post meta, where saving callback usually attached to `save_post` hook, `save_post` also fires to soon.

I think it's better to try **updated_post_meta** hook, which fires immediately after updating metadata of a specific type.